# JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 228 (char 227)

Tags: python, json, load

I am using Ipython to do some data analysis, I can't load the JSON file. Please help me to load this JSON file in IPython.
    And I also want to skip same words in the first line to make it a clean format, I want each record looks like this :

```
{"station_id":"72","num_bikes_available":18,"num_bikes_disabled":0,"num_docks_available":20,"num_docks_disabled":1,"is_installed":1,"is_renting":1,"is_returning":1,"last_reported":"1467164372","eightd_has_available_keys":false},
```

Here is  my code:

```
In [9]: path = 'stationstatus.json'

In [10]: records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
```

Here is the error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b1e0b494454a> in <module>()
----> 1 records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]  
<ipython-input-10-b1e0b494454a> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
//anaconda/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
320     if cls is None:
321         cls = JSONDecoder
//anaconda/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
340         end = _w(s, end).end()
341         if end != len(s):
--> 342             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
343         return obj
344
```

Here is part of my JSON file** :

```
{
  "last_updated": 1467164806,
  "ttl": 10,
  "data": {
    "stations": [{
        "station_id": "72",
        "num_bikes_available": 18,
        "num_bikes_disabled": 0,
        "num_docks_available": 20,
        "num_docks_disabled": 1,
        "is_installed": 1,
        "is_renting": 1,
        "is_returning": 1,
        "last_reported": "1467164372",
        "eightd_has_available_keys": false
    }, {
        "station_id": "79",
        "num_bikes_available": 1,
        "num_bikes_disabled": 2,
        "num_docks_available": 30,
        "num_docks_disabled": 0,
        "is_installed": 1,
        "is_renting": 1,
        "is_returning": 1,
        "last_reported": "1467163375",
        "eightd_has_available_keys": false
    }, {
        "station_id": "82",
        "num_bikes_available": 3,
        "num_bikes_disabled": 3,
        "num_docks_available": 21,
        "num_docks_disabled": 0,
        "is_installed": 1,
        "is_renting": 1,
        "is_returning": 1,
        "last_reported": "1467161631",
        "eightd_has_available_keys": false
    }, {
        "station_id": "83",
        "num_bikes_available": 36,
        "num_bikes_disabled": 0,
        "num_docks_available": 26,
        "num_docks_disabled": 0,
        "is_installed": 1,
        "is_renting": 1,
        "is_returning": 1,
        "last_reported": "1467163453",
        "eightd_has_available_keys": false
    }, {
        "station_id": "116",
        "num_bikes_available": 5,
        "num_bikes_disabled": 3,
        "num_docks_available": 31,
        "num_docks_disabled": 0,
        "is_installed": 1,
        "is_renting": 1,
        "is_returning": 1,
        "last_reported": "1467164693",
        "eightd_has_available_keys": false
    }, {
        "station_id": "119",
        "num_bikes_available": 15,
        "num_bikes_disabled": 0,
        "num_docks_available": 4,
        "num_docks_disabled": 0,
        "is_installed": 1,
        "is_renting": 1,
        "is_returning": 1,
        "last_reported": "1467160413",
        "eightd_has_available_keys": false
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: You are loading the file line by line. Try to first load the whole file and then give its content to the json decoder. The JSON part in your question is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion for loading the file:

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
records = json.loads(content)
```

The root object in your json will be in your `records` variable