# Merge JSON files JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, glob

**Goal:** Merge JSON files into one big file

**Background**: I am using the code below taken from here [Issue with merging multiple JSON files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520542/issue-with-merging-multiple-json-files-in-python)

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("/Users/EER/Desktop/JSON_Combo/*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(result, outfile)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 5733)
```

I checked [Python json.loads shows ValueError: Extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data) and [JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 228 (char 227)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577399/jsondecodeerror-extra-data-line-1-column-228-char-227) and [ValueError: Extra Data error when importing json file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474277/valueerror-extra-data-error-when-importing-json-file-using-python) but they are a bit different. A potential reason for the error seems to be that my .json files are a list of strings but I am not sure

**Question**: Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Comment: It sounds like one of your files is not valid JSON. I would recommend putting in a `try ... except...` and printing the file name in the `except` block to see which one is bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is an invalid JSON file in your files, found out which one caused it by catching the error with `try except`

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("/Users/EER/Desktop/JSON_Combo/*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        try:
            result.append(json.load(infile))
        except ValueError:
            print(f)

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Comment: I tried the code above and I get the follow error `NameError: name 'JSONDecodeError' is not defined`

Comment: thanks for the update. I re-ran the code and now I get the following `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str`'

Comment: @EER Try delete the `ValueError` and make it just `except:`

Comment: I did so. Now I get `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: it seems to not like the `json.dump(result, outfile)` line of code

Comment: I tried changing the `"rb"` to `r` as suggested on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t  but still get the same error

Comment: I think the problem is that my files aren't real json files - rather, each line of the file contains a json object.